# Insert the esc key under a vim buffer

Tags: vim

Sometimes I need to send <kbd>Esc</kbd> to the insert buffer. So I could generate for example the same thing when pressing <kbd>F8</kbd> under insert-mode.

So I thought mapping <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to the <kbd>Esc</kbd> actuall inserted key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert a literal esc by pressing ctrl 
-v (for "verbatim") and then esc.